# add_rewrite_rule not adding rule unless 'Custom Structure' is defined.

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hey the issue is just as the title suggests.

I'm wanting to use add_rewrite_rule to add a custom rule but these rules only get added in when 'Custom Structure' is selected in my permalink settings area.

Here's what I am calling on the init.

```
add_rewrite_rule("$slug/([^/]*)?", $this_path.'modules/module.redirect.php?permalink_name=$1','top');
add_rewrite_rule("custom-post-type-name=([^/]*)?", $this_path.'modules/module.redirect.php?permalink_name=$1','top');
```

Any ideas fellas?

Comment: Default structure is `/?p=123` and I don't see that pattern in your regex. I am not sure I understood your question and might be wrong, though.

Comment: add_rewrite_rule adds rules to .htaccess, for some reason when 'default' or any structure besides 'custom structure' is defined those custom rules are stripped out and not re-added into .htaccess.